# Transpose columns to rows keeping first column as it is in excel 2013 programitically

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data in the below format.

[image]

This is the result I am looking to achieve.

[image]

As I don't find any direct way in excel to transpose the data as per my requirement, so i am looking it  to do it programmatically but as i never wrote macro in VBA, can you tell me how can I proceed?

Comment: Regarding your question... Try to begin using the Macro Recorder on Excel. Just do whatever you wanna do and with a small research, you will get it. If you become stacked, we will be glad to help you.

Comment: Have a look at PowerQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume "Input table" housed in `A1:E4` include header

"Output table" criteria `G1:I1`: "Resource", "Skill" and "Value"

In "Output table" "Resource" column `G2`, copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$2:A$4)-ROW(A$1)/(B$2:E$4>0),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

In "Output table" "Skill" column `H2`, copied down :

```
=IF(G2="","",INDEX(B$1:E$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(B$1:E$1)-COLUMN($A1)/(INDEX(B$2:E$4,MATCH(G2,A$2:A$4,0),0)>0),COUNTIF(G$2:G2,G2))))
```

In "Output table" "Value" column `I2`, copied down :

```
=IF(G2="","",INDEX(B$2:E$4,MATCH(G2,A$2:A$4,0),MATCH(H2,B$1:E$1,0)))
```

Comment: Hi bosco_yip the 1st formula is not picking the next resource name, do I need to change something in formula?

Comment: 1] The "Output"f Resource name, in 1st formula G2:G10 return : "John","John","John","Bill","Bill","Mohan","Mohan","Mohan","Mohan". Then what do you wanted to return. 2] What is the meaning of "not picking the next resource name"? Give more information and example (Don't change anything in your original data prior to clarify your question)

Comment: Hi  @bosco_yip, it was my mistake while using the formula, the provided solution perfectly works for my need. You are super. Thanks a lot.